# Need PHP to multiple str_replace and jQuery text.replace

Tags: php, jquery

I have this line of code that will replace special character in php:

```
<?php echo str_replace(" +12,00$,"1200",$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel())) ?>" />
```

for this to work as i need, also the jQuery will have to include this code in other call:

```
jQuery("#productImg" + optionValueText.replace(' +12,00€','1200')).fadeIn('slow');
```

This will outpout `1200` and it will work good to add a span id for an image to load.
But i will have multiple prices, so i need automatic to do the work.

I need to make both codes to remove white space in the beggining  and characters `+`  `,` `€` from the price so allways it will display the price as 1200,4400,3399 etc.
For php i think i can do it if i play some time with the code but for jQuery line also?

Can somebody provide both codes please?

Thank you very much for your kind help!

EDIT:
the full php code that will load the image:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popWin('<?php echo $this->getGalleryUrl($_image) ?>', 'gallery', 'width=999,height=999,left=666,top=333,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;">
<span style="margin-top:-212px;"> <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" alt="no image" id="productImg<?php echo str_replace(" +12,00€","1200",$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel())) ?>" /></a></span>
```

and the jQuery that on dropdown change will control what image to hide and show.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// On document ready hide all images first

jQuery(".product-image2 img").hide();
jQuery("#off").hide();
jQuery("#productImgDefault").show();

jQuery("#<?=$colour_select_id ?>").change(function() {
    // Hide all images on slect element change action
     jQuery(".product-image img").hide();
     jQuery(".product-image2 img").hide();
      jQuery("#productImgDefault").hide(); 
         jQuery(".product-image .mousetrap").hide();                        


    // Get the value of selected option
    var optionValue = jQuery(this).attr('value');
    // Just a test to see if you're getting option value
    // alert(optionValue);

    // Get the content (aka inner HTML) of selected option
    var optionValueText = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#<?=$colour_select_id ?> :selected').text());

    // Just a test to see if you're getting right selected option inner text
    // alert(optionValueText);
 //  alert('Selected option has value: ' + optionValue + ' and inner text: ' + optionValueText);

    // Show the image based on selected value
    // Whatch out, case sensitive...

  if(optionValueText == "-- choose --") {
    jQuery(".product-image .mousetrap").show(); 
     jQuery("#on").fadeIn('slow');
      jQuery("#off").hide();
jQuery("#productImgDefault").fadeIn('slow'); } else { jQuery("#productImg" + optionValueText.replace(' +12,00€','1200')).fadeIn('slow');
  jQuery("#off").fadeIn('slow');
  jQuery("#on").hide();
}
  });

});
```

Comment: What mark-up is the JavaScript expected to work with? If you want to up-vote an answer click on the up-pointing triangle besides the answer (or to down-vote click on the downwards-pointing triangle). To accept an answer (if the answer was useful and answered your question) click on the tick-mark to the left of the supplied answer. Once the question is answered ***DO NOT*** 'close the thread.' The point of Stack Overflow isn't to help *you* with *your* problem, it's to help *everyone* with the *same* problem.

Comment: Thank you Topener and David. @David what do you mean about mark-up?The JS will reload an image inside a div when a dropdown change. If you need i can paste all the JS code but is very basic.

Comment: I mean the HTML mark-up. JavaScript, and therefore jQuery, work client-side. To offer help with JavaScript we need to see what it's expected to work with. So show the relevant HTML. And yes, please: the current relevant JavaScript would also be useful.

Comment: @DavidThomas i edited my post with the full code. Thank you

Comment: The **rendered HTML** not the PHP. Use 'view source' and paste the relevant piece of HTML into your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript:

```
optionValueText.replace(/[\+\s\$\,\€]/g,'');
```

PHP:

```
echo preg_replace('/[\+\s\$\,\€]/','', $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()));
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/^ \+?([0-9]+),([0-9]+)[\$€]$/','$1$2',$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel())) ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo str_replace(',','',trim($this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()),' +$€')) ?>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery("#productImg" + optionValueText.replace(/^ \+?([0-9]+),([0-9]+)[\$€]$/,'$1$2')).fadeIn('slow');
```

P.S. Not tested yet, may be some minor mistakes

Comment: thank you very much, unfortunattely it doesnt work. No errors in php or jQuery but the image doesnt change so something goes wrong on the creation of the span id for this image. Unfortunatelly i can't be sure cause the image will not appear and there is no error message to advise. In this code the whitespace before the +12,00€ is also removed? As i said in my 1st post if i use the simple str_replace and text.replace it will work. So i need something that will follow this pattern. Thank you.